# Why do I get dashed lines in my bar plot legend instead of filled rectangles?

Tags: pgfplots

### Question

Why do I get dashed lines in my bar plot legend instead of filled rectangles?
Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \begin{axis}[
        height          =   10cm,
        width           =   10cm,
        legend style    =   %
        {draw=none, legend columns = 2,at={(0.5,1.135)},anchor=north, font = \large},
        ]
        \addplot[
            ybar,
            bar width   = 3pt,
            line width  = 2pt,
            color       = green!50!black,
            fill        = green!50!black,
            ]
            table[x=xok, y=yok, col sep= comma]
            {histograms_OSNR.txt};
        \addplot[
            ybar,
            bar width   = 3pt,
            line width  = 2pt,
            color       = red,
            fill        = red,
            ]
            table[x=xnok1, y=ynok1, col sep= comma]
            {histograms_OSNR.txt};
        \addplot[
            ybar,
            bar width   = 3pt,
            line width  = 2pt,
            color       = orange,
            fill        = orange,
            ]
            table[x=xnok2, y=ynok2, col sep= comma]
            {histograms_OSNR.txt};
        \addplot[
            ybar,
            bar width   = 3pt,
            line width  = 2pt,
            color       = yellow!75!black,
            fill        = yellow!75!black,
            ]
            table[x=xnok3, y=ynok3, col sep= comma]
            {histograms_OSNR.txt};
        \legend{no impairment,span 3, span 2, span 1},
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output figure: [image: figure]

Here is the link to the data: [histograms_OSNR.txt](https://we.tl/t-1NhJcFQapj)

### Answer

Just adding "area legend," after the legend style is enough:

```
legend style    =   %
    {
        draw=none,
        legend columns = 2,
        at={(0.5,1.135)},
        anchor=north,
        font = \large,
        },
 area legend,
```

Comment: Please make your MWE compilable. `histograms_OSNR.txt` is unknown.

Comment: Yes sorry I forgot it, you can find it here: https://we.tl/t-1NhJcFQapj

Comment: Please, inset image to question. This link may after while be dead. Already now is not simple  accessible.

Comment: Better than insert code fragment into your question as solution of your problem, is extend it to an MWE and put it in answer. Then you can accept it yna by this inform audience, that your question is solved.